# Managing release versions across ~10 interconnected ruby/rails/capistrano/rabbitMQ services

Tags: ruby, web-services, version-control, architecture, service

So we are building a pretty hardcore app that consists of around 10 services - how should we best manage dependancies across app versions?

We took the decision to split things up into services, each one responsible for a small, logical task *(the word analyser just analyses the words, the words service allows other services to get information about words and special words, the classifier uses the data from the world analyser to perform a classification)*

The independent apps all have pretty well defined interfaces - but sometimes these change (a new field is needed for example).

When they change, we need to keep track of the fact that there is now a dependancy: version 0.2 of the analyser now requires version o.6 of the word service.

How do other people do this? What works and what is a pain in the ass?
We'd like to be able to release quickly and often. We already have jenkins toiling away running all the specs for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version your protocols and be backward compatible. v 0.2 of the analyser must work with the new version 0.6 of the word service **and** with the existing deployed v 0.5 of the word service. Deoployment will always be dance of several overlapping versions. BTW, interfaces *never* chnage. New *versions* of the interface are publishe, and both the client and the implementer must be able to distinguish which version is being used. Your services must degrade gracefully to all deployed versions of the protocols they interact with. You can retire versions once no longer deployed, *if* you can determine that is no longer deployed. If the the service/protocol is exposed publickly, you should maintain backward compatibility a **lot** longer.

[The REST Design Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00890OBFI) is a good read on the subject.